# How can I consistently maintain the Open on Phone option for notifications in Android Wear 1 and Android Wear 2?

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

In the original version of Android Wear, all notifications automatically created an Open On Phone option. In Android Wear 2, notifications do not automatically create this option.

Because my application does not have a companion Android Wear app, I would still like users to be able to open the phone application from a watch notification, but I would prefer not to have the "Open on phone" notification appear twice for users whose watches were unable to update to Android Wear 2.

Is it possible to remove the automatically added "Open on Phone" option from Android Wear 1 or to add a new "Open on Phone" option only if the user is using Android Wear 2?